# Manipulate rows using multiple clauses in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table that goes something like this:

**samples**

```
sample_id  | field    | value  | list_id
1            country    US       10
2            state      tx       10
3            country    US       11
4            state      tx       11
5            emp_size   100      11
```

I have a query that retrieves list_ids 10 and 11 using the ff code;

```
select * from samples where (field='country' and value='US') OR (field='state' and value='tx')
```

However I realized later on that this is not the setup that I want. Let say I include in my clause (field='emp_size' and value='100') because I want to get list_id 11 only, it still includes list_id 10 because I use OR in my query. And right now I'm not sure if there's a workaround for this using plain mysql only  or if I should just manipulate the data using php.

**Edit**

For clarification, I want to get the list_ids based on the given parameters, say, I want US and TX, it should return list_ids 10 and 11. But if I add another parameter, say, emp_size, it should only return list_id 11.

Comment: If you're looking for list_id why don't you select where list_id = "whatYouNeed"?

Comment: @genespos I can't. I have to get all list_ids that meet the given parameters. The above problem is just an example.

Comment: If want inclusive criteria why not use `AND`? Can you include your complete query in its final form and also explain in prose the data you are looking for?

Comment: You need to add more informations  to make your question more clear

Comment: @JRD It won't yield any result if I use AND

Comment: @genespos basically i want to get all list_ids based on the given parameters. Let's say I choose USA for the country and TX for the state then it should return 10 and 11, right? But if I include emp_size, it should only get list_id 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) style data structure, so the best solution here is to self-join the table for each parameter/value combination that you are searching on.

```
SELECT s1.list_id
    FROM samples s1
        INNER JOIN samples s2
            ON s1.list_id = s2.list_id
                AND s2.field = 'state'
                AND s2.value = 'tx'
        INNER JOIN samples s3
            ON s1.list_id = s3.list_id
                AND s3.field = 'emp_size'
                AND s3.value = '100'
    WHERE s1.field = 'country'
        AND s1.value = 'US';
```

Comment: WOW! I didn't know something like this exists. It's my first time encountering EAV. Thanks for this input. Anyway, it's now working. Maybe I just have concerns regarding the speed coz my data would eventually get bigger in the long run.

Comment: @user3360031 Those are legitimate concerns. There are plenty of advantages *and* disadvantages associated with using EAV that need to be weighed carefully. The link I included is a good primer to start with.