# Mysql filter from same column with multiple condition

Tags: mysql

Currently working in a project where i need to filter unique product id from multiple rows from same column with  different conditions

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `spec_property` (
`sp_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `spm_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `spec_value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `spec_last_value` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `spec_order_by` tinyint(2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=77 ;
ALTER TABLE `spec_property`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`sp_id`), ADD KEY `product_id` (`product_id`), ADD KEY `spec_value` (`spec_value`);
ALTER TABLE `spec_property`
MODIFY `sp_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=75;
INSERT INTO `spec_property` (`sp_id`, `spm_id`, `spec_value`, `spec_last_value`, `product_id`, `spec_order_by`) VALUES

(31, 23, 'Octa Core', NULL, 4, NULL),
(34, 26, '2048', 'MB', 4, NULL),
(35, 27, '8192', 'MB', 4, NULL),
(36, 28, '2048', 'MB', 4, NULL),
(69, 62, 'Android', NULL, 4, NULL),
(70, 63, '5', NULL, 4, NULL),
(71, 65, 'Yes', NULL, 4, NULL),
(72, 66, 'Yes', NULL, 4, NULL),
(73, 67, '32000', NULL, 4, NULL),
(74, 68, '25', 'fps', 4, NULL);CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `spec_property` (
`sp_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `spm_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `spec_value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `spec_last_value` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `spec_order_by` tinyint(2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=77 ;
ALTER TABLE `spec_property`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`sp_id`), ADD KEY `product_id` (`product_id`), ADD KEY `spec_value` (`spec_value`);
ALTER TABLE `spec_property`
MODIFY `sp_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=75;
INSERT INTO `spec_property` (`sp_id`, `spm_id`, `spec_value`, `spec_last_value`, `product_id`, `spec_order_by`) VALUES

(31, 23, 'Octa Core', NULL, 4, NULL),
(34, 26, '2048', 'MB', 4, NULL),
(35, 27, '8192', 'MB', 4, NULL),
(36, 28, '2048', 'MB', 4, NULL),
(69, 62, 'Android', NULL, 4, NULL),
(70, 63, '5', NULL, 4, NULL),
(71, 65, 'Yes', NULL, 4, NULL),
(72, 66, 'Yes', NULL, 4, NULL),
(73, 67, '32000', NULL, 4, NULL),
(74, 68, '25', 'fps', 4, NULL);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95329/3

```
SELECT distinct(product_id)
FROM `spec_property`
WHERE (spm_id = '62' AND spec_value IN ('Android' , 'Windows'))
    AND (spm_id = '27' AND spec_value BETWEEN 4096 AND 131072 )
```

If I use the 'OR' condition I can get this result:

( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95329/1 ). Actually i need to find product id's which are matches the filter options like

> Select distinct(product_id) from spec_property where spm_id_62 IN
>   ('Android' , 'Windows') and spm_id_27 BETWEEN 4096 AND 131072

Comment: i think if you use `OR` in above query you get only distinct product_id 4. right?

Comment: Hey Jacky, as you mentioned using an OR statement will allow you to get both the Android/Windows, 62 values AND the 27 values. Your original query doesn't make sense as it asks for conflicting values (i.e. spm_id=62 & spm_id=27). It's not clear what you actually need, could you elaborate?

You will get just the id of 4 as you asked for distinct id's (and they are all 4's)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813037/manipulate-rows-using-multiple-clauses-in-mysql

Comment: Did you expect which product id have `spm_id 27 and 62 and spec_value is 'Android' , 'Windows' and between 4096 AND 131072` ?? Right????

Comment: Actually query should be like this

Select product_id from table where spm_id_27 in ('Android', 'windows') and spm_id_62 between 4096 AND 131072

Answer (score 0):

Use OR

```
SELECT distinct(product_id)
FROM `spec_property`
WHERE (spm_id = '62' AND spec_value IN ('Android' , 'Windows'))
    OR (spm_id = '27' AND spec_value BETWEEN 4096 AND 131072 )
```

Comment: already i mentioned in my question i used 'OR'  but it need to use 'AND'

Comment: jacky both ids in condition is **spm_id** or is **sp_id** @jacky

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to find products that match all of your filters, you can use the [self join solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813037/manipulate-rows-using-multiple-clauses-in-mysql).

Another way to find all products that match all filters, assuming spm_id is unique per product id.

```
SELECT product_id
FROM `spec_property`
where (spm_id = '62' and spec_value in ('Android' , 'Windows'))
or    (spm_id = '27' and spec_value between 4096 and 131072 )
group by product_id having count(*) = 2; -- number of filters
```

Comment: i will use many conditions in  **SPM_ID***  ---------

    Select distinct(product_id) from spec_property where spm_id_62 IN ('Android' , 'Windows') and spm_id_27 BETWEEN 4096 AND 131072 and spm_id_26 BETWEEN 4096 AND 131072  and spm_id_23 in ( 'octa core','dual core' )

Comment: Then just keeping adding each one as either a join or adjusting the count equality.

Answer (score 0):

Did you expect this one???

```
 select distinct(a.product_id) from `spec_property` a
 inner join `spec_property` b on
 a.product_id=b.product_id and a.spm_id = '62' and a.spec_value in 
('Android' , 'Windows') and b.spm_id = '27' and 
 b.spec_value between 4096 and 131072
```

Comment: i will use many conditions in SPM_ID* --------- Select distinct(product_id) from spec_property where spm_id_62 IN ('Android' , 'Windows') and spm_id_27 BETWEEN 4096 AND 131072 and spm_id_26 BETWEEN 4096 AND 131072 and spm_id_23 in ( 'octa core','dual core' )